# Casablanca/cpprestsdk listener.support accepting functions but not methods

Tags: c++, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

To support HTTP methods using Casablanca/cpprestsdk you can use code like this

```
   http_listener listener(U("http://localhost:10000/restdemo"));
 
   listener.support(methods::GET,  handle_get);
   listener.support(methods::POST, handle_post);
   listener.support(methods::PUT,  handle_put);
   listener.support(methods::DEL,  handle_del);
```

This works fine when handle_get, handle_post, etc. are simply functions. But as soon as I try to implement this inside a Controller class with handle_get, handle_post, etc. being methods I get errors like:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Controller::handle_get()’
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Controller::handle_get(web::http::http_request)
```

I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1experimental_1_1listener_1_1http__listener.html) for why methods wouldn't work. I also perused through the [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues) and didn't see anything relating to my problem.

Is there any obvious reason why listener.support would struggle to find the methods?

Comment: You can't pass a method pointer to something that expects a function pointer. Try using a lambda

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the methods

```
listener.support(methods::GET, std::bind(&Controller::handle_get, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`http_listener::support` accepts a parameter of type `const std::function< void(http_request)> &handler`, that means that you can pass any [Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) type, so, in order to use a member function, you can use the following:

```cpp
listener.support(methods::GET, [this](web::http::http_request http_request)
{
    // call your member function here or handle your request here
});
```

or

```cpp
listener.support(methods::GET, std::bind(&MyClass::my_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

The first example uses a lambda with `this` captured, the second creates a call wrapper over function `MyClasss::my_handler`